# Social Media Icons Wont Lay Side By Side

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure this out. I know its easy for most. I have used float left and right but I can't seem to get the Three Social Media icons at the very top of the site to lay down side by side.

You can find the site here: http://cmrlawenforcement.com/default.asp

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="socialcontainer">
<span class="connect info">
<ul>
  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/CMR-Law-Enforcement-Testing-    Review/100299806688670" title="Be our friend" target="_blank" class="facebook">Facebook</a>        </li>
  <li><a href="https://twitter.com/cmr_policeprep" title="Follow us!" target="_blank" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?    id=37905494&authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=Xbtq&locale=en_US&srchid=695550441389940130460&srchindex=1&srchtotal=333&trk=vsrp_people_res_name&trkInfo=VSRPsearchId%3A695550441389940130460%2CVSRPtargetId%3A37905494%2CVSRPcmpt%3Aprimary" title="Let's connect" target="_blank" class="linked">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for it:

```
 /* Social Media Sprites */
 .socialcontainer {float: right; width 300px;}

 .connect ul {
  list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding-right: 15px;
 }
 section.connect li {

      margin: 7px 0;
      margin-right: 5px;
 }
 .connect li a{
      display: block;
      width: 24px;
      height: 24px;
      text-indent: -999em;
      background: url(../images/menubar/socialmedia_sprites.png) no-repeat;
 }
 .connect li:last-child {margin-right: 0;}
 .connect a.facebook {background-position: left top;}
 .connect a.facebook:hover {background-position: left bottom;}
 .connect a.twitter {background-position: -24px top;}
 .connect a.twitter:hover {background-position: -24px bottom;}
 .connect a.linked {background-position: right top;}
 .connect a.linked:hover {background-position: right bottom;}
```

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out what is causing them to all stay on top of each other. Can any suggest what I am doing wrong?

Note: The social media icons are a sprite but I don't believe that would cause the problem.

Let me know if you have any questions?

Thank you!
Frank

Comment: try `display: inline-block` rather than `display: block`

Comment: @JordanForeman I changed the display to inline-block but still messed up and other suggestions? http://cmrlawenforcement.com/default.asp Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
.connect li {
    float:left;
}
```

Or:

```
.connect li {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Your list items have default styling, so to get them next to one another you need to change the display or float property.

Comment: I have it so that the icons can lay on there side now but how do I hide the text from showing?

Comment: What text? And on your site they're just stacked on the left now.

Comment: Yes I don't want the text I just want the icons. And I want them to the far right side of the site. But I'm not doing to good with this as you see :(

Comment: Do you see facebook, twitter and linked text over the icons?

Comment: Now I see the text and the sprites are also all messed up. Not sure what changes you're making.

Comment: The icons are messed up because of the text. It making the layout wider.

Comment: OK, in your `.connect li a` rule you have `display: inline-block width: 24px;`. You're missing the semi-colon between those two rules. It should be `display: inline-block; width: 24px;`. Making that one change seems to fix it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xeBSV/2/

Comment: UGggggggggggggggggggggggg stupid little things. Thank you! now for me to get them all to the far left side of the screen do I just do a float: right; in connect ul? Thanks for everything

Comment: Never mind I think I got it. I changed float: left; in connect li to right. that seemed to get it. Now I just have to clean it up a little more. I can't thank you enough!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've already accepted an answer, but I'd hate to let this fiddle go to waste:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVVfS/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="linkedin">LinkedIn</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;    
}

ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul li a
{
    display: block;

    background: url('http://cmrlawenforcement.com/images/menubar/socialmedia_sprites.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;

    color: transparent;
}

.facebook
{
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.facebook:hover
{
    background-position: 0 -24px;
}

.twitter
{
    background-position: -24px 0;
}

.twitter:hover
{
    background-position: -24px -24px;
}

.linkedin
{
    background-position: -48px 0;
}

.linkedin:hover
{
    background-position: -48px -24px;
}
```